# pass parameters to entrypoint in the docker

Tags: docker

I have a console tool that can be executed like this

```
tool -r -b -n -x -k 'Some data'
```

I want to run the tool in the container but pass arguments from outside.

My Dockerfile installs the tool and the dependencies. I set there the entry point as

```
ENTRYPOINT ["tool"]
```

I want to execute it like this

```
docker exec --env USER=user1 .. -r -b -n -x
```

where it would be equal to `tool -r -b -n -x`. But it fails because `exec` doesn't have the parameter `-r`. How to make it pass the parameters to the container itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker exec` execute an aribtrary command in the container and does not take `ENTRYPOINT` into account.

If you want to add arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT` you should pass them when you execute `docker run`, you canno't pass arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT` once the container is started.

Comment: however, @lapots, you probably want to use `docker run` for this, not `docker exec`.  It doesn't make sense to have a long lived container running just so you can invoke your tool there.  Invoke the container with `docker run` and probably `--rm` to invoke your tool.